# Text field with formatting "None" being wrapped in <p> tags EE2.9.2

Tags: text-formatting, formatting

ExpressionEngine (pre 2.7.2) used to have an issue where it would start outputting p tags around normal text fields that have default formatting set to "None".

The very-temporary fix (which still works) is in the answer here: [Why is Text Formatting: None wrapping <p> tags around my text?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14379/why-is-text-formatting-none-wrapping-p-tags-around-my-text)

This bug has returned on a website we have running EE 2.9.2 and keeps breaking functionality on the site.

Has anyone else noticed the return of this issue? Or does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Did these fields formerly have a different format? When you change a field's format, old (existing) entries will not change unless you check the box to update existing entries while editing the field (to not break old content).

Comment: I'm aware of that, yes. That's how I temporarily "fix" the problem, by changing to XHTML then back to none and select the "Update all existing entries" checkbox which fixes it. But then, a few days later, the client reports the issue again.

Comment: Do you allow format override in the publish page? Maybe they are doing it inadvertently?

Comment: No it's being populated programmatically. I'm getting updates every night from an API and writing them into the channel titles and channel data table. No P tags to be seen anywhere.

Comment: Ah, ok. Writing directly to the database via an add-on or external script is a key detail; can you update your question to add that and include how you're doing it as well as the queries you are using? Field format is set per-row and it sounds like you may be missing something in your implementation.